# jquery inverse of div selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, inverse

I'm trying to get an event when a user selects a row and drops it outside a jquery grid.
This is the drop function for a drag/drop happens within the grid, which works perfectly fine -

```
    $(".grid-canvas")
        .on("drop", function (e, dd) {
              // somecode
                    });
```

I'm trying to track the drag & drop happening "ANYWHERE" outside the grid canvas div. but the inverse selection does not seem to be working.
I tried this, but not working -

```
$(".grid-canvas")
    .not(this)
    .on("drop", function (e, dd) {
     alert("outside");
 });
```

I tried this, but it triggers for drag & drops within the grid as well -

```
$(":not(.grid-canvas)")
                               .on("drop", function (e, dd) {
                                alert("outside");
                            });
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Target the document directly to get all drops, and then just filter out anything that is nested inside `.grid-canvas` yourself (probably more efficient than pseudo selectors) :

```
$(document).on('drop', function(e, dd) {
    if ( ! $(e.target).closest('.grid-canvas').length ) {
        // dropped outside
    }
});
```

Comment: I really dont know what would be a more resource friendly solution, both have a weaknesses. One solution will be resource intensive at event triggering other on the binding time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read up on the "on" documentation so you have a better understanding.  Your second example says the following:

```
Select all elements with the "grid-canvas" class
  ...that aren't `this`
  ...and watch for drop events on them, and do this when they happen
```

Which clearly isn't what you want.  The second is closer:

```
Select all elements that don't have a grid-canvas class
  ...and watch for drop events on them, and do this when they happen
```

Which is closer, but a) adds event listeners to almost every single element in the page, which is a really bad idea, and b) will still fire for elements *inside* your grid-canvas div, which is what you're seeing, since you still attached listeners to them.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
Select a high-level element (e.g. `body`)
  ...listen for a drop event, and check if the drop event happened on .grid-canvas or one of its children
```

Which would look something like:

```
$('body').on('drop', function(evt) {
  //Check if the element dropped on has a .grid-canvas as a parent
  if($(evt.target).parents('.grid-canvas').length == 0) {
    alert('Outside');
  }
}
```

There are several ways to check if the target is within .grid-canvas, the one I used is just an example.  You could also do `$('.grid-canvas').has(evt.target)`, for instance - go at it from the other way around, which might make more sense depending on how you think about it.

But overall: jQuery isn't English, and you can't just string together commands that *sound* like they should do what you want.  Make sure you read up on the functions you're using and understand what they do, and you'll build your jQuery skills much quicker.